# Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table - How could I retrieve an item operation status if it is inserted or merged using insertOrMergeOperation?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I'm recently using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table API and I noticed there was a great method called [InsertOrMergeOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet#insert-or-merge-an-entity), however, I am wondering if there is any way that the return result could tell me whether my entity just did an insert or a merge/update operation. I checked the TableResult object but it doesn't return any useful information about that.

Is there anyone know if this Operation could give me what I want? If not, is there any other operation that could perform the same workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TableResule does not return a value to indicate if it's an insert or merge operation. If you want to get the info, you have 2 methods for that:

Method 1:use [table query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-table#query-by-using-linq) with **partition key and rowkey** to check if the records exists or not in table, then you know the following operation by `InsertOrMerge()` is insert or merge as per the result is null or not, sample code like below:

```
CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("People");

TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>()
    .Where(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Email", QueryComparisons.Equal,"Ben@contoso.com")
    ));

await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<CustomerEntity>(query, null);
```

Method 2:use try-catch block, and first do a insert operation, if it returns an "conflict" error message, means the following `InsertOrMerge()` operation is an merge operation, code like below:

```
            TableOperation t1;

            try
            {
                t1 = TableOperation.Insert(customer);
                table.Execute(t1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message.ToLower() == "Conflict".ToLower())
                {
                    t1 = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(customer);
                    table.Execute(t1);
                }
            }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's the same solution I took previously in my approach which is two step job: retrieve and insert/update, I was hoping that maybe using the `InsertOrMerge()` could do the one-step job instead of two but looks like at least for now it's not possible.